# Not able to get token from XERO

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to get access token for XERO API but no luck, can anyone please help me here.

I am having client id, secret key and other required details.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple resources which might help you get started:

Insomnia walkthrough to test out api calls
https://devblog.xero.com/insomnia-client-xeroapi-auth-1c4cf485f251

SDKS and sample apps in 6 supported languages
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/libraries/overview

For machine-machine integrations
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/machine-2-machine

Our youtube channel has videos that compliment these resources
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7DA_vntKKChsenzpL7QWPg

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to call XERO service endpoint to get the token, then what all steps should i follow.